# How to find the limit of $\frac{\tan(2x)}{\sin(3x)}$ as $x$ approaches $0$ analytically?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I'm taking a calculus 1 course, and I'm running into issues when trig gets added into the mix. I keep trying to simplify $\frac{\tan(2x)}{\sin(3x)}$ so that I can either plug in $0$ or find one of the special limits, but I always end up at a dead end.

I've looked for existing help, but everything seems to use L'Hopital's rule. We haven't gotten to derivatives yet, so that wouldn't be an acceptable answer to turn in.

Answer (score 2):

The computation can be done simply as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\tan 2x}{\sin 3x} &=&\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin 3x\cos 2x} \\
&=&\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\left[ \sin x\color{red}{(2\cos 2x+1)}\right] \cos 2x} \\
&=&\frac{2\cos x}{\color{red}{(2\cos 2x+1)}\cos 2x}\rightarrow \frac{2\cdot 1}{(2\cdot
1+1)\cdot 1}=\dfrac{2}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
No L'Hospitale's rule, no Taylor series, no limit of  $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$  too!

(Thanks to P.S. :) )

$\bf EDIT$ The  misprint is now corrected. Thanks to Blue who pointed out to $\color{red}{it}$.

Answer (score 1):

We just need to recall that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x} = a, $$
hence:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(2x)}{\sin(3x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos(2x)}\cdot\frac{x}{\sin(3x)}\cdot\frac{\sin(2x)}{x} = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$\frac{\tan2x}{\sin3x}=\frac23\frac{\sin2x}{2x}\frac{1}{\cos2x}\Big/
  \frac{\sin3x}{3x}\ .$$
You should see some known "special limits" here.

Answer (score 0):

when trying to find the limit of $\dfrac{\tan 2x}{\sin 3x} = \dfrac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x\sin 3x}$  one can see that the $\cos 3x $ in the numerator is harmless can be evaluated to $1.$ finding the original limit is reduced to finding the limit of $\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(3x)}$ here we make further simplification that $\sin(small) = small + \cdots$ so that when the argument to $\sin$ is small, you can erase the word $\sin$ leaving the small argument. in this case finding the limit is reduced to finding $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{2x}{3x}.$ that is clearly $\dfrac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

With *equivalents*: $\, \sin ax\sim_0 ax,\enspace \cos ax\sim_01$, hence $\tan ax \sim_0 \dfrac{ax}1=ax$. Hence:
$$\frac{\sin 2x}{\tan 3x}\sim_0\frac{2x}{3x}=\frac23,$$ 
which proves the limit is $\dfrac23$.